# gettype() leaking memory

Tags: php, twitter, xdebug, twitter-oauth

I'm using the [twitter-async library](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-async-documentation.html) to do some oauth calls to twitter but ultimately, a lot of memory is being used up. I tried running the xdebug execution trace and this is where I feel the memory is getting leaked.

`json_decode()` is using 47077232 bytes. Okay. This is fine.

But `gettype()` ? Why should this too be using similar amount of memory?

How could this be prevented?

The script runs in a loop and the memory usage keeps going up. I'm using `gc_collect_cycles()` at number of places and it is showing improvement. But this one, I can't understand why should this happen.

```
  724.1772   47077232 +2118720             -> json_decode() /var/www/html/includes/classes/twitter/EpiTwitter.php:230
  724.1926   49157104 +2079872             -> gettype() /var/www/html/includes/classes/twitter/EpiTwitter.php:232
  724.1927   49157104       +0             -> property_exists() /var/www/html/includes/classes/twitter/EpiTwitter.php:240
  724.1927   49153520    -3584     -> EpiTwitterJson->__destruct() /var/www/html/includes/classes/twitter/EpiTwitter.php:0
  724.1949   46714808 -2438712     -> in_array() /var/www/html/cron.php:156
```

Comment: I don't know if gettype is leaking memory but I know for sure that gettype is slow like hell! Maybe you can migrate from gettype to is_*

Comment: Can you show the exact command you are using?

Comment: @Pekka Couldn't get you. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php):

> Never use gettype() to test for a certain type, since the returned string may be subject to change in a future version. In addition, it is slow too, as it involves string comparison.
>
> Instead, use the is_* functions.

e.g. use `is_array`, `is_string` etc.

Comment: The result is same, using is_object isn't reducing memory usage at all.